# Woocommerce: Which function create an order?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working on an android app based on a 3 Tier architecture. I have set up a products page and the <kbd>Pay Now</kbd> button integrated with PayPal. I also receive `Success` message after successful payment.

I'm now stuck at the order function. Which function of Woocommerce makes the order?

I'm simply trying to pass the price, product_id and other details to that particular function which will take care of the rest of the process.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: more than 2 hours still no answer!

Comment: There is a function 'create_order' in file 'wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\class-wc-checkout.php'. Hope it is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code that will generate an order. You'll have to substitute in your payment gateway class

```
    // create a new checkout instance and order id
    global $current_user;
    $product_id = $_POST['productId'];
    $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
    $order = wc_create_order(array(
        'customer_id' => $current_user->ID,
    ));
    $order->add_product( $product, 1 );
    $order->calculate_totals();
    $my_gateway = new WC_Gateway_WhateverGatewayYouAreUsing();
    $payment = $my_gateway->process_payment($order->id);
    if($payment["result"] == "success") {
        $order->update_status('completed');
        wc_add_notice("Thank you!");
    }
    else {
        $order->update_status("cancelled");
        wc_add_notice("oh no! plz send me da moneez", 'notice');
    }
```